# determine outer normal unit vector of $\{(x,y,z)|y^2+z^2\leq1\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to calculate the outer normal unit vector $n$ for the boundary of
$$
A=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1,x\ge0\}
$$
So I have $\partial A=\{(0,y,z)|y^2+z^2\le1\}\cup\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x\ge0\}$.

Cleary for the second set I get $n_2=(x,y,z)^T$ for a point $(x,y,z)$.

For the first one I've thought about  $n_1=(-1,0,0)$ using pictures, right? So how can you calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your surface is the level set of a function $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ (for example $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^3;f(x)=0\}$), then a normal to the surface $S$ at a point $x$ is given by the gradient $\nabla u(x)$, provided it is nonzero.

For example, the second part of your surface is a part of the sphere $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^3;x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\}=\{x\in\mathbb R^3;f(x)=1\}$ where $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$.
The gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(x)=(2x_1,2x_2,2x_3)=2x$.
If we want to normalize it to unit length, we can divide out the two (or in general take $\nabla u(x)/\|\nabla u(x)\|$).

The first part of your surface is $\{(x,y,z)|x=0,y^2+z^2\le1\}$; it is convenient to write the set so that all coordinates are free and then restrictions are given.
(This refers here to including the silly condition $x=0$.)
Now you can choose $f(x,y,z)=z$ and your surface is part of the set where $f=0$.
The normal is given by the gradient of $f$: $\nabla f(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$.

Comment: okay, but my problem was more the other set with $\leq$. any hint?

Comment: @sheldoor, I expanded my answer.

Comment: thanks, but the outer one would be $(-1,0,0)$ if I got it right.

Comment: @sheldoor, yes. My method does not give the orientation, so you have to check it separately. But that is only a problem of finding the correct sign.

Comment: yeah, thank you very much.